# python parsing text/plain email

Tags: python, email, parsing

Suppose I have an email which looks like this:

```
From hostname Tue Jun 15 21:43:30 2010
Received: (qmail 8580 invoked from network); 15 Jun 2010 21:43:22 -0400
Received: from mail-fx0-f44.google.com (209.85.161.44)
by ip-73-187-35-131.ip.secureserver.net with SMTP; 15 Jun 2010 21:43:22 -0400
Received: by fxm19 with SMTP id 19so170709fxm.3
for <username@domain.com>; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.103.84.1 with SMTP id m1mr2774225mul.26.1276652853684; Tue, 15
Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.123.143.4 with HTTP; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Tue, 15 Jun 2010 20:47:33 -0500
Message-ID: <AANLkTikFsIjJ3KYW1HJWcAqQlGXNiXE2YMzrj39I0tdB@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: TEST 12
From: Full Name <username@sender.com>
To: username@domain.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

ONE
TWO
THREE
```

I know I can use `msg = email.message_from_string(str)`, and `msg['To']` to get `username@domain.com`, but **How do I identify the "ONE TWO THREE" at the bottom?**  Bonus!  How do I identify all the "Received:" k/v pairs at the top?  When I try:

```
msg['Received']
```

I only get the first one.  How do I get the second one?

Answer (score 1):

This only addresses the "bonus": You can use `msg.get_all('Received')`.

```
>>> msg.get_all('Received')
['(qmail 8580 invoked from network); 15 Jun 2010 21:43:22 -0400', 'from mail-fx0-f44.google.com (209.85.161.44)']
>>> msg.get_all('Received')[1]
'from mail-fx0-f44.google.com (209.85.161.44)'
```

Side note, you can explore `dir(msg)` and `help(msg)` in the interpreter.

Comment: upvoted for teaching how to use help() and dir(), incredibly useful functions i miss in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I can identify "ONE TWO THREE" from the body of the email with this code:

```
msg.get_payload()
```

Yaah me!